# Unable to create FULLTEXT INDEX in MYSQL for Arabic Text

Tags: mysql, arabic, full-text-indexing

I have have a large MySQL database.  One table 'news' has over 6million entries.  Two columns are Arabic language text.  I am able to create an index for the two columns using:

```
mysql> CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX news_index ON news(news_title, news_text);
```

but the index is empty and I receive the following error when I try to execute a fulltext search:

```
mysql> SELECT news_title FROM news WHERE MATCH(news_title) AGAINST('أردوغان');

ERROR 1191 (HY000): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

The database used InnoDB and UTF-8.  The column encoding was utf8_unicode_ci, I thought that may be the problem so I changed the two columns to utf8_general_ci.

When I created the index, the index list shows:

```
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| news  |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | news_id      | A         |     4293286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| news  |          1 | fk_news_1_idx |            1 | news_country | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| news  |          1 | news_index    |            1 | news_title   | NULL      |     4293286 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| news  |          1 | news_index    |            2 | news_text    | NULL      |     4293286 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I have also tried making an index with just:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE news ADD FULLTEXT(news_title, news_text);
```

But again, no luck.  I am missing something, when I create the index, it runs for over an hour so *something* is happening.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your fulltext index is applied on both `news_title,news_text` columns, you should use both of the to in `MATCH()` keyword

```
SELECT news_title FROM news WHERE MATCH(news_title,news_text) AGAINST('أردوغان');
```

Comment: So simple!  That worked, I didn't realize I had to run against both columns if the index was created for both.